# Trouble building DLookUp expression to get value from a query into a mainTable

Tags: vba, ms-access

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT tblFinal.[Vendor Name], DLookUp("[State]","qryRef","[Vendor Name] = '" & [Vendor Name] & "'") AS State
FROM tblFinal;
```

I have one table [tblFinal] and one query [qryRef].
tblFinal and qryRef both share a [Vendor Name] column.
qryRef is set up to gather State, Zip, and other columns from a third table [refVendorImport] based on a match in tblFinal.[Vendor Name] and refVendorImport.[Vendor Name w/Pcard Text String]

```
SELECT tblFinal.[Vendor Name], refVendorImport.[Vendor #], refVendorImport.[State Abbrv], refVendorImport.State, refVendorImport.Location, refVendorImport.[postal code], refVendorImport.[IMPLAN Postal Code], refVendorImport.[Cong# District], refVendorImport.[IMPLAN CONG# DISTRICT], refVendorImport.[Consolidated Vendor Name], refVendorImport.[ISR/SSR NAICS], refVendorImport.[IMPLAN NAICS], refVendorImport.[Vendor #1]
    FROM refVendorImport INNER JOIN tblFinal ON refVendorImport.[Vendor Name w/Pcard Text String] = tblFinal.[Vendor Name]
    GROUP BY tblFinal.[Vendor Name], refVendorImport.[Vendor #], refVendorImport.[State Abbrv], refVendorImport.State, refVendorImport.Location, refVendorImport.[postal code], refVendorImport.[IMPLAN Postal Code], refVendorImport.[Cong# District], refVendorImport.[IMPLAN CONG# DISTRICT], refVendorImport.[Consolidated Vendor Name], refVendorImport.[ISR/SSR NAICS], refVendorImport.[IMPLAN NAICS], refVendorImport.[Vendor #1];
```

My goal is to create a new query that can take specific column values from [qryRef] based on [Vendor Name] to populate [tblFinal] blank values via DLookup 
However, I am getting an error compiling the function -

> The Visual Basic module contains a syntax error. Check the code, and then recompile it.

This is the expression I had built to get State

```
SELECT tblFinal.[Vendor Name], DLookUp("[State]","qryRef","[Vendor Name] = " & [Vendor Name]) AS State
FROM tblFinal;
```

New Error: [image: syntax error]

What is causing the error? Is my expression even built correctly? Do I have to reference the specific tables the columns are coming from? 
In the query so far, I have [tblFinal] and [qryRef] showing with a [Vendor Name] connection.

Additional Information: Due to the nature of the imports, I realize column naming is not very optimal.

Comment: You probably need quotes around the last [Vendor Name] and you probably do need to specify the table since they both have a Vendor Name column.

Comment: Why DLookup and not joining table/query? Text fields require apostrophe delimiters for parameters: `"[Vendor Name] = '" & [Vendor Name] & "'")`. Is there a VendorID could search on instead? This will not actually save data 'into a mainTable'.

Comment: Edit question to post the entire SQL statement. If query name is qryRef then why use qryReftest in DLookup?

Comment: @June7 good catch on my query name. I meant to say qryRef in the expression. There is no vendorID I can search on. The only common column is [VendorTxtString] which can be "B&H PHOTO MOTO 800-606-6969 US10001" as an example

Comment: Again, conflicting info. Is field name [VendorTxtString] or [Vendor Name]? Why use qryRef and not just tblImport? If there are multiple identical fieldnames pulled into query then yes, must include table/query name as qualifier to distinguish: `tblFinal.[Vendor Name]`. Edit question to show sample tables and query statements.

Comment: Hi @June7, thanks for your patience with me. I have edited my post for more clarification as well as attempts I have made. Please let me know if there is still anything you want to clarify or if I should just give up on the Dlookup

Comment: Why would error message reference Visual Basic module? You have not posted any VB code. DLookup does not include apostrophe delimiters as already advised needed. Why does tblFinal not have [Vendor #]? DLookup in a SELECT will not actually populate field in table - that would require an UPDATE. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Hi @June7, you are right, I had missed  your apostrophe delimiters as advised.

Comment: @June7 tblFinal does not have [Vendor #] because it is a separate imported excel spreadsheet table. My next step is to use use UPDATE now that I have the value! 
Also, unfortunately I have no control in the naming convention the tables :(